# uninitialized constant Admin::ModeratorsController::ModeratorInteractor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, interactors

Hi i am working on a RoR project with ruby-2.3.0 and rails 4. I am trying to call a method of interactor from controller. My controller is inside the Admin directory as follows:

```
class Admin::ModeratorsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  include Interactor

  def index
    ModeratorInteractor.find_abc(params)
  end
end
```

My interactor is:-

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ModeratorInteractor
  def self.find_abc(params)
    User.all
  end
end
```

When i run my code i got an error `uninitialized constant Admin::ModeratorsController::ModeratorInteractor`.
I also try to include the Interactor:-

```
include Interactor
```

Please help how to fix it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `ModeratorInteractor` as `module` to include it in your controller:

```
module ModeratorInteractor
  def self.find_abc(params)
    User.all
  end
end
```

Then you need to ensure that the module is loaded properly:

```
# in application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W("#{config.root}/lib") # path to your module
```

Or you can also use `require` instead of `autoload_paths`:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/modeator_interactor"
```

Then in your controller, you can include it:

```
include ModeratorInteractor
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to `include Interactor` in your `ModeratorInteractor`, also you need to define a `call` method, not `find_abc` which will not work and it will throw and error of `undefined method`, so your final interactor will look like this

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class ModeratorInteractor
  include Interactor

  def self.call
    params = context.params
  end
end
```

and you will call it as

```
ModeratorInteractor.call(params: params)
```

Voila.